# Load a .dne file in pgmpy

Tags: python, parsing, file-format, bayesian-networks, pgmpy

The popular proprietary software [Netica](https://www.norsys.com/netica.html) uses, among others, the [`.dne` format](https://www.norsys.com/WebHelp/NETICA/X_File_Formats.htm) to store Bayesian networks.

How can I load a `.dne` file in [`pgmpy`](https://pgmpy.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small script with a function that will read a `.dne` file and construct a `pgmpy` model accordingly. [Link](https://gist.github.com/Jsevillamol/f9f0282486f834af8a19b46777a9fd4a)

It will only work with discrete networks with only regular nodes (ie no utility nodes). I have tested the code on a couple of networks but it is likely that the code contains some bugs.